# Can't get the 'title' in a particular class tag in Beautiful Soup 4 using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am a Python newbie and I am trying to make a web crawler with Beautiful Soup 4 in Python3, that scraps You Tube data. When the link of the channel is entered it scraps the channel name, description of the channel, the videos posted by the channel, number of views and links to those videos.
Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re
import requests


def Info_channel():
    links=link.get()
    r=requests.get(links)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
    channelname= "Channel Name:" + soup.title.string
    first=Label(text=channelname,fg='yellow',bg='black').place(x=0,y=0)
    vid_name,viewstr,view_count,disp_link=None,None,None,None

    placer=0
    placer1 = 0
    space = 0

    for name in soup.find_all('a',class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"):
        vid_name=name.text
        second=Label(text=vid_name,fg='black',bg='white').place(x=200,y=40+space)
        space=space+20

    desc_list=soup.find_all(attrs={'name':'description'})
    desc=desc_list[0]['content']#.encode('utf-8')
    third=Label(text=desc,fg='black',bg='yellow').place(x=0,y=20)
    for view_find in soup.find_all('li'):
        viewstr=view_find.text
        view=re.findall('[0-9]+,[0-9]+ views',viewstr)
        for views in view:
            view_count=Label(text=views,fg='blue').place(x=650,y=40+placer)
            placer=placer + 20

    for all_links in soup.find_all('a',class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"):
        vid_link=all_links.get('href')
        final_link="https://www.youtube.com"+vid_link
        disp_link=Label(text=final_link).place(x=750,y=40+placer1)
        placer1=placer1+20


gui=Tk()
gui.geometry('500x400')
gui.title('YouTube Crawler')
label=Label(text='Paste Link Here',fg='blue')
label.pack()
link=StringVar()
entry=Entry(gui,textvariable=link)
entry.pack()
channel=Button(text='Crawl this Channel',fg='white',bg='black',width=30,command=Info_channel)
channel.place(x=10,y=45)

entry.focus_set()
url=entry.get()
gui.mainloop()
```

The problem I am having is in this part :

```
for name in soup.find_all('a',class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"):
        vid_name=name.text
        second=Label(text=vid_name,fg='black',bg='white').place(x=200,y=40+space)
        space=space+20
```

For eg:

https://www.youtube.com/user/MetallicaTV

Above link has a  video in the  channel  that on Inspecting Element gives

```
a `class ="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2" dir="ltr" title="Metallica: Hardwired (Official Music Video)"`
```

I want to extract the title , i.e "Metallica: Hardwired (Official Music Video)" part .

Now the problem that I face is that , the code does not Enter the above mentioned for loop (for name in soup.find_all.............) at all , so the Extraction part does not begin !!

Please suggest where am I going wrong ?

The Output i get:
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBUsW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are selecting an element with multiple classes, there can only be one space between each class name in the string.

In other words, the following line:

```
class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"
#                                          ^^        ^^
```

Should be:

```
class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link spf-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"
```

Therefore, in your case you would need to update your loop to:

```
for anchor in soup.find_all('a', class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link spf-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"):
    print(anchor.text)
```

I would recommend using the `.select()` method instead though:

```
for anchor in soup.select('.yt-lockup-video a.yt-uix-tile-link'):
    print(anchor.text)
```

---

In response to your comment below, if you are trying to get the views, you can use:

```
view_tags = soup.find_all('li', text=re.compile("[\d,]+ views"))
for view_tag in view_tags:
    views = re.findall(r'[\d,]+', view_tag.text)[0]
    print(views)
```

Comment: Man , you beauty!! You saved me , it now displays the Video names perfectly. But the second for loop:for all_links in soup.find_all........... is still left untouched ,I removed the  spaces as you said in this loop also , but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Man , you beauty!! You saved me , it now displays the Video names perfectly. But the second for loop:for all_links in soup.find_all........... is still left untouched ,I removed the spaces as you said in this loop also , but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: @AyushGoyal - Did you try: `for link in soup.find_all('a', class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link spf-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"):`?

Comment: Aah yes , I got it Working , another problem though :p , I am able to display the views upto 6 digits only , i.e , if views are 28,765,322 , it displays 765,322 only

Comment: @AyushGoyal - Yeah, that's because `[0-9]+,[0-9]+` should be `[\d,]+`